# Saving DOMSource object created into a folder in SFTP Server in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, dom, sftp

I need to save the newly created `DOMSource` object as new XML file into a folder inside the SFTP server (not transferring a file from local computer into SFTP).

Here is the code

```
public void save(String xmlFilePath, Document document) {

    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    transformerFactory.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, "");
    transformerFactory.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_STYLESHEET, "");
    Transformer transformer;
    try {
        transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(document);
        StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(new File(xmlFilePath));
        transformer.transform(domSource,streamResult);

    } catch (TransformerException | NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [JSch SSH/SFTP library](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/).

1. Afaik, it's the most widely used SFTP library for Java
2. It supports uploading data from streams.

   I assume that its [`ChannelSftp.put` overload that returns `OutputStream`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html#put-java.lang.String-) can be [hooked to your `StreamResult`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/stream/StreamResult.html#StreamResult(java.io.OutputStream)) (instead of the `File`).

   ```
   StreamResult streamResult =
       new StreamResult(channelSftp.put("/sftp/path/file.zml"));
   ```